# How to import service in Domain?

Tags: grails

How to import service in Domain?

It has a field where I need to fill a field with a protocol. The protocol is automatically generated and created a service excluvivamente for this generation.

In the field in method 'AfterInsert' was inserted a call to this service that automatically populates the field.

I put on bootstrap the creation of some objects that need to be filled in your field with this protocol. But an error occurs which is apparently due to the use of 'Services' in 'Domain'. Could anyone help me?

```
class Post {

    static transient postService

    String conteudo
    Date dataCriacao = new Date()
    String protocolo

    static constraints = {

        dataCriacao(nullable:false, blank:false)
        conteudo nullable:false, blank: false 
        protocolo nullable: true, blank: true 

    }

    static mapping = {  
        conteudo type: 'text'
        sort dataCriacao:"desc"   
    }

    def afterInsert(){
        if(!this.protocolo){                   
            registraProtocolo()
        }
    }

    protected void registraProtocolo() {
       postService.teste(this)
    }
}

Error: ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in com.app.post.Post entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>  105 | doCall             in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2

Message: null id in com.app.post.Post entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>  105 | doCall             in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     27 | recInsertProtocolo in com.app.post.PostService
|     83 | teste . . . . . .  in     ''
|    117 | registraProtocolo  in com.app.post.Post
```

Comment: What is the content of postService.teste?

Comment: Just a function to change the protocol attribute:

def teste(Post post){


        post.protocolo = "START"

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved! It is a matter of logic. The service comes automatically setados as 'transational = true', using AfterInsert the error occurs due to this feature of the service. but if you use a closure 'withNewSession', this problem is solved and is allowed to change the attributes of objects with services once the new session will meet the requirement 'transational'. Just got my domain like this:

```
AfterInsert def () {

     if (! this.protocolo) {

             Post.withNewSession
             {

                  registraProtocolo ()


             }

     }

 }

 protected void registraProtocolo () {
    postService.teste (this)
 }
```

**Thank you all for the help**

[For those who want more information down a JIRA who helped me in this solution (read the comments)](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4851)

Answer (score 4):

The `postService` shouldn't be static, it should be simply

```
transient postService
```

Comment: I've tried with **transcient** and even declaring the service as **def** but the error occurs when I try to change the data field. If I put the function and to implement other services only will have no problem, but if the function changes an attribute of the same object being 'AfterInsert' says the ID is null **Message: null id in entry com.app.post.Post (do not flush the Session after an exception Occurs)**. So I do not know how to make the service change the attribute of the object without this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post {

    def postService

    ...
}
```

ref: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#dependencyInjectionServices

Comment: Although not stated in the main documentation, it's good to get into the habit of using `transient` for your autowired services in case you need to make the class serializable in future (e.g. if you want to start using [web flow](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow)).

Comment: I read the documentation, but the strange thing is that in the case of no documentation attribute of the object is changed and when I use the service to change an attribute error occurs in 'afterInser'. The impression I have is that hibernate does not persist the information in the database when running the 'AfterInsert'.

Comment: Note that the error message is null id in entry com.app.post.Post (do not flush the Session after an exception Occurs).